# Black-clock icon overlay?

Tags: file-attributes

While I was cleaning up some (very) old files, I decompressed a `.zip` file which contained some old files from 1989. I was surprised to find that *some* of the files are showing a black clock icon overlay as seen below.

I opened a command-prompt and checked them with `attrib`, but found nothing unusual. I also checked the *Advanced Attributes* dialog for them and still found nothing unusual.

What the heck is going on and how can I get rid of it?

**Figure 1**: Windows Explorer showing files with black-clock overlays

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer showing unknown black-clock icon overlays]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Meaning

[According to Microsoft’s Raymond Chen][1], it is one of the more baffling icon overlays (probably due to its rareness). The black-clock overlay is the [NTFS extended attribute][2] “offline” which indicates that it has been backed up to tape. In other words, the file is not currently accessible without first mounting the correct tape.

## Explanation

“*But I don’t have a tape drive!*” I hear you object. That is not surprising; neither do I. Raymond explains:

> The black clock is particularly baffling because you sometimes see it even if your system is not equipped with Hierarchical Storage Management. When this happens, it's because some program (typically a setup program) didn't check error codes properly.

In my case, the file was created in 2010, likely in Windows 7 (it is stamped as being made in 2010). It was decompressed in Windows XP onto an NTFS volume created by Windows 7. A bug in 7-Zip or the contents of the file itself has probably caused an inconsistency that led to this bizarre behavior.

## Observations

Windows XP’s `attrib` command cannot show the attribute because XP was released in 2001 and is limited to the basic `RASH` attributes (it does not show a few other attributes that can be seen in Vista+). However, if you enable the *Attributes* column in Windows XP Explorer, you can see the attribute indicated by an `O`.

A curiosity caused by the attribute is with the `dir` command:

```
1989.01.19  09:53            11,800 AGUY0.CMP
1989.01.19  09:54          (10,912) AGUY1.CMP
```

As you can see, `cmd` indicates any files marked as being offline by enclosing their sizes in parentheses. It does not however affect the *total bytes* indicated at the bottom.

You can also use PowerShell to view it:

```
>  dir * | select Name, Attributes | more

Name                                                                 Attributes
----                                                                 ----------
AGUY0.CMP                                            Archive, NotContentIndexed
AGUY1.CMP                               ...emporary, Offline, NotContentIndexed
```

Another (messy) way to see it is to use the `fsutil` command:

```
> fsutil usn readdata AGUY0.CMP
…
File Attributes  : 0x2020
…

> fsutil usn readdata AGUY1.CMP
…
File Attributes  : 0x3120
…
```

You’ll notice that the attributes of the second file include the `0x1000` bitmask of the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE`  attribute constant.

One curious (though understandable) observation is that in Vista+, the files that are marked as offline are automatically also marked as non-indexed (i.e., the `I` attribute). However, using `attrib` to remove the `I` attribute **does not** strip them of the offline attribute; they no longer have the non-indexed attribute but remain marked as offline.

**Figure 1**: Screenshot of offline files in Windows 7 Explorer

[image: Screenshot of offline files in Windows 7]

## Solution

You can strip the attribute with the `attrib` command from newer versions of Windows. If that is not feasible, then you can also use a shell-extension like Febooti’s  [FileTweak][4] or [Attribute Changer][5]. You can also use an alternative to `attrib` or even `cmd` itself like JPSoft’s [Take Command][6]. PowerShell [can also be used][7] to [access and modify extended attributes][8], but it’s not as nice as `attrib` or a shell-extension.

Answer (score 2):

It means the file has been [archived to tape](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030827-00/?p=42783).

Comment: Yes, I know, except that I don’t have a tape drive. I found that page while researching. I said hold on because I was typing up a (more detailed) answer that includes explanatory information and actual solutions.